# How to use function pointers or virtual functions to allow another programmer to define a function's implementation?

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++

I am writing a program that performs a basic set of operations, but allows the user to fill in the specific functions that are called (and they choose those functions before compiling). For example, my program may call a function `filter(input,&output)` but the user can write their own filter.

The ways I've read about that may solve this problem are function pointers and virtual functions. It looks like I can either do something along the lines of

```
int (*pt2Filter)(float,&float) = NULL;
int IIRFilter(float input, float &output);
pt2Filter=&IIRFilter;
```

for a function pointer. But that doesn't let me keep track of internal states in the filter.

Or I could make a class `myClass` with a virtual `filter` function, and then the user would make an `IIR` class that inherits from `myClass` and overwrites the `filter` function.

```
class myClass
{
    virtual void Filter(float input, float &output);
    ...
};

class IIR : public myClass
{
    float stateVariable;
    virtual void Filter(float input, float &output);
}

void IIR::Filter(float input, float &output)
{ //IIR filter done here }
```

I guess my question is how do I call the filter function from my program without knowing that an `IIR` class even exists?

Or if I'm going about this completely wrong, how do I go about calling my `Filter` function when my goals are to 1: let the user define whatever filter they want. 2: Don't allow the user to change my source code

**Update**
 This may have not been as difficult as I first thought. I created a header file where the users will say which function they want the Filter class to call using the line

```
//User types this into "FunctionImplementations.h"
#include "IIR.h"
typedef IIR FilterImplementation;
//then I just type
#include "FunctionImplementations.h"
FilterImplementation.filter(); //Implements IIR classes filter function
```

Comment: You do this : `myClass *p = get_implementation();` where `get_implementation()` returns a pointer to an object of any derived class. Once you have `p`, you can do this : `p->Filter(arg0, arg1);`. This is dynamically dispatched and therefore will call the implemention of the derived class (whatever it is) which the user doesn't know anything about.

Comment: Pass a `myClass` reference to your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve this kind of polymorphism.

The main question is whether you need *compile-time* polymorphic behavior or *run-time* polymorphic behavior. In the first case, the solution is usually to define a function (or class) template to perform your generic work, and have it parameterized with the type of the callable object to be invoked by your generic code for doing the customized part of the job:

```
// This is how you would define your generic procedure
template<typename F> void do_something(F f, ...) 
{ 
    ...
    f(...); 
    ... 
}

// This is how you would use it...
void my_func(...) { ... };
do_something(&my_func, ...); // with a function pointer

do_something([] (...) { ... }, ...); // with a lambda

struct my_functor { operator void () (...) { ... } };
do_something(my_functor(), ...); // with a functor
```

If the type of the object which defines the customized behavior is determined only at *run-time*, then you have two possibilities: either you use `std::function<>` for encapsulating your callback, or you go with the virtual function approach. I personally would prefer the former, because it does not force you to create a hierarchy of inheritance just for the purposes of achieving dynamic polymorphism.

This is how you use a `std::function<>` object:

```
void my_func1(int, int) { ... }
void my_func2(int, int) { ... }

std::function<void(int, int)> fxn = &my_func1;
fxn(2, 3);
...
fxn = &my_func2;
fxn(3, 4);
...
fxn = [] (int x, int y) { ... };
fxn(4, 5)
```

This is how you could take advantage of it for defining your generic procedure:

```
void do_something(std::function<void(int, int)> f, ...)
{
    ...
    f(3, 4);
    ...
}
```

At this point, you can invoke `do_something()` with anything that can be assigned to an `std::function` (i.e. any callable object with a compatible signature).

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to be done at **compile-time**, you may consider using templates over inheritance. An example:

```
template<typename Derived> // Derived is having DoActualWork
class WorkerBase
{
public:
   DoWork()
   {
       ((Derived*)this)->DoActualWork();
   }

};

class MyWorker : public WorkerBase<MyWorker>
{
public:
   void DoActualWork() {...}
};
```

Here `MyWorker` is inheriting from class template  `WorkerBase` passing itself as type-argument to template. The conversion from `this` to `Derive` is needed, and will work, since **this** object is actually derived class.

Note that this is one of the technique for compile-time polymorphism, using classes. Through templates, you may have such feature in other ways. `std::map` can be used with `std::greater`!

Comment: So I write the `WorkerBase` class, then somebody else writes the `MyWorker` class. What would I type to call DoWork()?

Comment: That is simplified example, for early binding using inheritance. `DoWork` may or may not be called by instance of any-worker class. The method `DoActualWork` is supposed to be called by you. It like calling `operator <` for a comparison, where said operator will be given by client (still and early binding - no pointer, not virtuals).